# Exporting remote data and Socket Reuse in RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I am new to RMI so please forgive me if my question is silly. 
I am trying to export a data in concurrent manner. How can I reuse the same port for exporting more than one remote object at once.
Can anyone guide me to achieve this with an example?

I tried to do this so first object got exported but got following exception at the time of second export.

`java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 55580; nested exception is: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind`

I used following code snippet

`UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(remoteObj, 55580);`

If I skipped the port number than any port number will be picked by RMI. Like as below

`UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(remoteObj)`

In my case port number is fixed for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I reuse the same port for exporting more than one remote object at once

That's what happens by default. All remote objects exported from the same JVM that

- don't specify a port number, or specify port zero, and
- don't specify server or client socket factories, or specify the *same* socket factories as determined by `equals()`

will be exported on the same port.

I conclude that you must be exporting your remote objects from two JVMs. THere's no real need to do that. Put them all into one. If you start the Registry from in there as well, with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`, you can use the Registry port 1099 for everything, and it's already reserved at IANA, so no arguments about the number.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Yes, you concluded right. My JVM is different from the Registry one. As I understood your answer, if I export object in JVM where Registry exists then during export If I not mention the port number than all the object got exported on 1099. Am I right? Second If I need to do the same thing from different JVM then can I set the port 55580 as default for RMI. So it will automatically take it when I use following `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(remoteObj)`. In my case I can't use the Registry JVM.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. You will need a distinct port per JVM. The question then becomes why you think you need separate JVMs.

Comment: I have to used already existed Registry. That JVM is common for other services also. So I can not use that JVM. I will be grateful to you if you explain me your point  `You will need a distinct port per JVM`. If I skipped the port in `exportObject` method then RMI will pick any port. Is this port will remain the same for all the other exports? In this case how we handle firewall issue? Here firewall issue means I have to open port for firewall. Please forgive me if I sounds silly.

Comment: You will need a distinct port per JVM. You can't share them. I can't state it more simply than that. The firewall issue you have now raised is a brand new question, but the solution is either to open all the ports required or to eliminate your restriction on JVMs. There is no architectural reason for it. Your requirements appear to me to be over-specified, and not to have been written with enough knowledge about how RMI actually works.

Comment: [Re your now-deleted comment] So what exactly is the question? It seems bizarre to dictate multiple JVMs and therefore multiple ports when you could economize on both by using one JVM and one port.

Comment: Thanks @EJP for your prompt response. One last question. As we know that port 1099 is reserved for RMI. Is there any specific port range which RMI chooses to export data?

Comment: No. It uses whatever the system gives it, as does any other TCP program. The concept of 'port ranges' is foreign to the TCP API, although some operating systems implement it at the kernel level. NB This is not 'export[ing] data'. It is exporting *remote objects*, which are essentially *services.*

Comment: `.when you could economize on both by using one JVM and one port`. We are using XIB integration brocker. JVMs are under the control of XIB. For load balancing more than One JVM can create. These JVMs will interact with Central JVM where Registry reside. I am just trying to clear the architecture.